# How to maintain updates to summary tables after some source data is deleted

Tags: php, mysql, materialized-views

I came across materialized views, which look great:
http://en.oreilly.com/mysql2011/public/schedule/detail/17146

However there is too much "detail" data, and I'm forced to delete it at the end of each day...  Is there a way I can still take advantage of flexviews or something like it to handle my summation logic?

For context, this script logs page views (of which their are too many for me to store all details about indefinitely), and I'm looking to build summary tables to answer longer term reporting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little bit vague but I try to answer what I extracted from your question. Assuming you have a table with a lot of detailed data which you truncate over time to keep it manageable and you want to keep summaries of your data.

A proper way to achieve that is to have a corresponding statistics table where you aggregate certain statistical data for larger time frame (e.g. a day). To do the actual statistical analysis you would need to sum your statistical data, but this will be easy as the structure should be simple enough for aggregation queries.